# AngularJs File Upload without FormData

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, file-upload

I've made a simple drag and drop directive for file uploading, but my main concern is that i need to have IE8/9 support, so taking in account that FormData is not supported, how can i do a multiple file upload without using the `FormData` object?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
What i'm trying do do is this:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function () {
      var upload = $http.post('awesomeFileThatWantsMultipleFilesUploaded.php',
                 angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('droppable')).scope().files,
                 {withCredentials: true,
                  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
                  transformRequest: angular.identity})
           .success(function (response) {
               });

      return upload;
   }
```

But the problem is that when the browser doesn't have support for `FormData`, i initialize the `files` variable as `array`, and then i push each file to the variable. If the file is `FormData`, this works.

Comment: This module https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload is good. It supports native HTML5 uploads using FormData, but degrades to a legacy iframe upload method for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make this by hand. Is rather messy and you will always have problems. You can use a polyfill for formdata, like [moxie](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie), for angular I use [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) there is even a way to upload to S3 from the browser ([here](https://github.com/nukulb/s3-angular-file-upload))

If you want to do it by hand, check the code in those repositories and find some ideas

Comment: Plupload doesn't have support for IE9, and moxie is based on it. angular-file-upload, as you can see [here](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/blob/master/dist/angular-file-upload.js) on line 89, also uses formData, which I want to avoid, because of the ie9 support.

Comment: https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload#-old-browsers yeah you need the html5 polyfill, check the problems to avoid issues with those browsers